# .scrollLeft() doesn't work in Chrome (Jquery)

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, scroll

I'm making a horizontal website that automatically scrolls to the middle of the page when the document has loaded (the page width is equal to 3 times the window width). But the code I use doesn't work in Chrome.

I'm using this method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(this).scrollLeft(value);
});
```

I checked it on other browsers ( even on a tablet ) and it works exactly how I wanted. But chrome doesn't do anything at all. ( There is no error ).

Does anybody have a solution? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a Fiddle demonstrating your problem?

Comment: in the function defined in your `document.ready`, `this` is not specifically defined.. point the selector to an element.

Comment: Here is the website : http://ally-design.com/two/

Comment: Works here. Are you just refreshing the page? Browsers remember the scroll bar position, and that will occur after the JS here fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this).scrollLeft(value);` is not good. `$(this)` is pointing to `$(document)`. It should be `$("body")` or `$("#parentdiv")` as appropriate.

Use the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#parentdiv").scrollLeft(value);
});
```

And change `parentdiv` to the id of the element which surrounds all your content. Without seeing all your CSS, I can't really help any more than this.

Answer (score 0):

$("#el").animate({ scrollLeft:110 }, "fast");